# link_to with a select attribute

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, coffeescript

I have a select that take one provider

```
  <%= form_for @claim do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :provider_id, {}, {include_blank: "Select option"}, {id:       "provider_selector_resend", style: "width:100%;"} %>
  <% end %>
```

In the same page i have a link_to(in the show) that take the attributes of this and duplicates the data

```
  <%= link_to "Resend", resend_claim_path(params[:id]), id: "resend_button", class: "button tiny", style: "margin-top: 12px;"%>
```

the dup method in the controller

```
  def resend
      copy_claim = Claim.find(params[:id])
      @claim = copy_claim.dup
      @claim.items << copy_claim.items.map {|it| it.dup}
      @claim.updates << copy_claim.updates.map {|up| up.dup}
      @claim.client_id = current_user.company.id
      @claim.resend_id = copy_claim.id
      if @claim.save
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:success] = "Reenvío enviado con éxito"
      else
        flash[:notice]= "Error al reenviar el reclamo "
      end
  end
```

My problem is that I want the link_to to take the select (which is a provider_id) and replace it with the provider_id of the dup (@claim = copy_claim.dup - Copy it here).